# Controlling which instance of a class is created in a base project

Tags: c#, oop, overriding, virtual, extending

I have a base project in which I cannot make changes, and so I made my own project extending the base.

So in the base there is, let's say

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int NumberOfPeople = new BaseConstans().GetNumberOfPeople 
}
```

And then `BaseConstants` looks like this:

```
public class BaseConstants
{
    int _numberOfPeople = 5;
    public virtual int GetNumberOfPeople
    {
        get
        {
             return _numberOfPeople;
        }
    }
}
```

In my project I then have:

```
public class ProjectConstants : BaseConstants
{
    int _numberOfPeople = 10;
    public override int GetNumberOfPeople
    {
        get
        {
             return _numberOfPeople;
        }
    }
}
```

So what do I need to do in order for my `ProjectConstants` to be called, when running my project, but still allowing the people using the base to call `BaseConstants`? I hope there is a way to do this

PS: This is a simplified example

Comment: `new ProjectConstans().GetNumberOfPeople` ?

Comment: and also please make this method static `GetNumberOfPeople ` so you can eliminate instantiation

Comment: If you mean you want `ClassA` to call `ProjectContants.GetNumberOfPeople` instead of `BasConstants.GetNumberOfPeople` then you could only do that by modifying `ClassA` which if I'm reading your answer properly you don't have access to and therefor, no you cannot do that.

Comment: @juharr Exactly. All right, then I will have to find some other solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please try executing below lines of code

```
ProjectConstants pc= new ProjectConstants();
console.WriteLine(pc.GetNumberOfPeople());// this will call the extended class's method
ClassA ca= new ClassA();
 console.WriteLine(ca.GetNumberOfPeople());// this will call the  class A's method
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the idea is that the OP wants `ClassA` to use `ProjectConstants`.

Comment: @juharr Yup, I think so

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, if you can't modify the source code of the project containing the class using `BaseConstants`, you won't be able to force it to use `ProjectConstants`.

That base class would need to look as follows to support your scenario:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(BaseConstants constants)
    {
         Constants = constants;
    }

    private BaseConstants Constants { get; }

    public int NumberOfPeople => Constants.GetNumberOfPeople(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this implantation I could cast the `ProjectConstants` to `BaseConstants` so the `GetNumberOfPeople` will return 5 rather than 10

```
  class BaseConstants
  {
    public int GetNumberOfPeople { get; set; } = 5;
  }

  class ProjectConstants:BaseConstants
  {
    public new int GetNumberOfPeople { get; set; } = 10;
  }
```

And here how could cast to base class

```
  var pc = new ProjectConstants ();
  Console.WriteLine(pc.GetNumberOfPeople); // => 10
  Console.WriteLine((pc as BaseConstants).GetNumberOfPeople); // => 5
```

Hop this will solve your problem.